# enter next for iteration only when the last ajax request complete in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array noti_array which has two elements, noti_array[0]='meghan&3', noti_arra[1]='tylor&5', the username and number concatenated by '&', in each iteration, I want to send the username to a ajax request

```
for(var i=0;i<noti_array.length;i++)
{

    var mesg_array = new Array();
    mesg_array=noti_array[i].split('&'); 
    who_sent=mesg_array[0]; //first iteration, meghan
    sent_num=mesg_array[1]; //3

    //send the user name to a ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url:'getLastCon.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{who_sent:who_sent},
        success:function(data){
          alert(who_sent);
          }
     });
 }
```

this code above would not alert meghan and tylor, instead, it alerts twice tylor, and if I use a 'break' after the ajax request, it would alert meghan once only, I think it's probably the loop enter the next iteration even the ajax request have not completed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `who_sent` could be a global variable. In that case, because of the asynchronous nature of your AJAX calls, the alert would trigger for the last assigned value of `who_sent`. Make `who_sent` a local variable or add another variable by adding var: `var who_sent = mesg_array[0];`.

**Edit:**
The above is wrong on how variables persist in a loop. I'm sorry for the inaccurate info. The following code will do what you want:

```
for( var i=0 ; i < noti_array.length ; i++ ) {

    var mesg_array = noti_array[i].split('&');
    who_sent = mesg_array[0]; //first iteration, meghan
    sent_num = mesg_array[1]; //3

    (function(who) {
        //send the user name to a ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getLastCon.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: { who_sent:who },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(who);
            }
        });
    })(who_sent);
}
```

Comment: the loop would loops through 2 times, if I have var who_sent inside the loop, will it have an issue like redeclared?

Comment: No. The scope of the variable is inside the loop. So, at the end, the variable is destroyed and then recreated the next time through.